# Running JetRacer on the 2GB version of Nano with Waveshare JetRacer Pro AI Kit

Tags: nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm trying to run jetracer on the 2GB version of Jetson Nano along with Waveshare's JetRacer Pro AI Kit but all the release files [listed in the docs](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/jetracer/blob/master/docs/software_setup.md#latest-release--but-not-yet-fully-verified--) are for the 4GB version. The [Waveshare wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/JetRacer_Pro_AI_Kit) also features files for the 4GB version only. I've seen someone [mention](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/jetracer/issues/96#issuecomment-822535379) there being a pre-built 2GB version for Waveshare cars available on the wiki alongside the 4GB version but it's not there anymore (he meant the AI Kit instead of Pro AI Kit I have but still, it's unavailable for either anymore).

Is there no way to run the AI capabilities for self driving RC cars on a 2GB jetson, then? I thought these were cross platform and worst case scenario, there'd be worse performance - but not impossibility to run it altogether. Would it make sense to flash the card by hand using [Jetson's official docs](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/learn/get-started-jetson-nano-2gb-devkit#intro) and then trying to follow the Jetracer Setup Guide from [step #2](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/jetracer/blob/master/docs/software_setup.md#step-2---power-on-and-connect-over-usb) instead? This seems to have a chance of working cause step #1 (the one with ready-baked files) is just an installation of Jetcard anyway so one should be able to bypass it by flashing the card yourself instead of using the provided image. At the same time, I contacted Waveshare's support and they just told me straight away that Jetracer and their kit won't work with a 2GB Jetson and that's that...

Is there a possibility to run Jetracer on a 2GB Jetson then?